# Invalid object name 'tbl_Shading_Analysis'.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I am trying to insert textbox value into database in my asp.net project. While using this code some errors are generating. Please help me.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        con.ConnectionString = (@"connectionString");
        con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText=("INSERT INTO tbl_Shading_Analysis(Load_Band) VALUES ('"+txtLoadBand.Text+"')");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I means the table `tbl_Shading_Analysis` doesn't exist in the connection you are using, it may cause if you have some triggers attached with the table there may be some issue.

1. Check if you are connected to the right `server/database`.
2. Check any triggers that run on that table as well and make sure all of them have the exact table name spelled correctly.
3. Try to use the full schema for the referenced table if you have checked above two point for correctness.

   Ex:  [DatabaseName].[Schema].[TableName] or [Database1].[smmdmm].[aid_data]

Answer (score 1):

That error is coming because the table `tbl_Shading_Analysis` does not exist in your database.

1. Check your connection string if you have given the correct database name.
2. Check if you have created that table in the specified database.
3. Check if the spelling of the table name is different from what you have specified